# Angular SPA, using server-side-rendering to support IE11? Is this risky or a smart way to go?

Tags: angular2, internet-explorer, single-page-apps

I'm working on a dozen enterprise SPA's and PWA's and most of them require impeccable IE11 support. This has been a complete pain with countless problems every step of the way.

It occured to me recently that I could just focus on implementing SSR (server-side-rendering) instead and completely bypassing the need to support IE.

I however don't have a lot of experience with SSR and wanted to ask about how this could come back to haunt me or if any more experienced developers have had to make this choice/how it worked out for you?

Comment: falling back to SSR doesn't sound like impeccable support to me.

Comment: @SebastianRedl that was a third degree burn mate. Spent a few more hours looking into SSR and Angular Universal and I'm leaning towards just working out the bugs of Angular with IE11 as a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further research and consulting I decided to just put the effort in and properly support IE.

It really wasn't that hard either after a bit of tweaking. Angular took care of most JavaScript problems and I only had to focus on CSS issues.

By far the biggest issue was CSS and things just not aligning/responding properly. Flexbox is not well supporrted on IE11 it seems.

Ended up just putting everything in a div and putting more effort in on the parrenting of html elements but still using FxLayout directives.

Product is shipped and is used by hundreds of IE clients daily with no issues.